# Ownership Partners Grouping using excel VBA

Tags: excel, database, vba

I have data which shows the acquisition of property from one partner to another and transfer of properties. Based on the inactive date and then seeing the document date I have to detect the transfer of property. Here is the snap of data:

[image]

For example in the second picture when the contract inactive date passes, ownership transfers to other having document date of the next day. Like in first group the 13th one William G & ALMA have ownership now look inactive date it is 10/3/1971, now I will find the next day date in document dates which I found 10/4/1971 for ALMA TEST TR, therefore, ownership transferred to him and new partners are WILLIAM G & ALMA TEST TR as both make to 100% of ownership. Here the output I have done manually but I need a VBA code to make it easier as I am new to VBA here is the required output.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Sub DateFill()
Dim rng As Range, destRow As Long
Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet
Dim c As Range '-- this is used to store the single cell in the For Each loop

Set shtSrc = Sheets("Input") ' Sets "Sheet1" sheet as source sheet
Set shtDest = Sheets("Output") 'Sets "Sheet2." sheet as destination sheet
destRow = 2 'Start copying to this row on destination sheet

    Dim x, y, i As Long
    y = Array("ERROR", "(ERROR)") ' To delete rows having the name error to clean data

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1)
        x = .Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(LCase(x(i, 1)), y, 0)) Then x(i, 1) = ""
        Next
        .Value = x
        .SpecialCells(4).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

' >> Look for matching dates in columns F to G <<
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If (c.Offset(0, 2).Value + 1 = c.Offset(1, 3).Value) Then

        shtSrc.Range("A" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("A" & destRow)
        shtSrc.Range("B" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("B" & destRow)
        shtSrc.Range("C" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("C" & destRow)
        shtSrc.Range("D" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("D" & destRow)
        shtSrc.Range("E" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("E" & destRow)
        shtSrc.Range("F" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("F" & destRow)
        shtSrc.Range("G" & c.Row).Copy shtDest.Range("G" & destRow)



        destRow = destRow + 1

' > Ends search for dates <
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

It's over my knowledge level. Any help would be appreciated, as I can't seem to figure this code out. If you could explain how this works in simple terms, that would be equally awesome!

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do (it is very unclear which rows are grouped together and why). Also your question is not clear: *"… explain how this works in simple terms"* explain what? • Try do descibe step by step or a data set (group) what steps you do manually. How it looks before, then which steps you do (what you compare, what you copy, etc) and how it looks in the end.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Dear, basically I have to transfer partnership from one person to other, like when the last highlighted Inactive date the ownership transferred to the person having one day afterward document date. Now, these two are grouped together, start from the last. One owner remained the same while other changed. Similarly it moves upwards.

Comment: Still unclear what will be grouped together and why. I actually hoped for a **much** more detailed explanation of all the steps you do manually ([edit]ed into your question, comments are not sufficiant). Reading [mcve] might help you to improve the question. Otherwise this will be too broad to answer I think.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ when the contract inactive date passes, ownership transfers to other having document date of next day. Like in first group the 13th one William G & ALMA have ownership now look inactive date it is 10/3/1971, now I will find the next day date in document dates which I found 10/4/1971 for ALMA TEST TR therefore ownership transfered to him and new partners are WILLIAM G & ALMA TEST TR as both make to 100% of ownership.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I hope you will get now.

Comment: Very tricky indeed..

Comment: @werdakloi what will happen if 2 ownerships change at the same date?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yes when both ownership changes WILLIAM G & ALMA TEST TR in group 11 both become inactive on 9/19/1995 then it will see the dates of next day in document date i.e 9/20/1995 and find the new owners group 10 JOANN A, WILLIAM A & WILLIAM G TR ESTATE.

Comment: OK, I don't get it. Maybe this helps you: You can use the formula `=MATCH(G:G+1;F:F;0)` to get the row number of the "document date" that is corresponding to the "inactive date". Eg for the last yellow marked date it will return the row number of the first yellow mark.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ there is only one simple logic when the inactive date changes % ownership shifts to the next person having next day document date and in this way groups are formed. Moving downward to upwards in the second picture.

Comment: Can you please take one full example (that will result in one **full** group from beginning to end) out of the source data to show how the result would be generated? • You are taking the inactive date `10/3/1971` add +1 to the day and look it up in document date so you find `10/4/1971`. But what happens next? What will you do next step-by-step? Please explain it by [edit]ing your original questions (commenst are too short for that).

Comment: Please note on input page, rows 21 and 22. That is the first group on output page, row 47 and 46. On 10/03/1971 (inactive date) that ownership became inactive and transferred to row 45 on 10/04/1971 (doc date). That is difference between the group's. When a line item becomes inactive it is replaced in the following group, which is determined by doc date most of the time.

Comment: The thing is I can't follow your description of row numbers because they are cut off in your screenshot. And I'm not going to count them, sorry.

Comment: I have edited the snap, 21 & 22 are the last rows of picture 1

Comment: But why are 21 & 22 one group? How can you see that in the source data?

Comment: Because their % is 50+50 = %100

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196132/discussion-between-p-and-werdakloi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following data as sheet `"Data"`. Note that the columns need to be in exactly this order and position. The code addresses the columns by A, B, C …

Note that I used another date format, but the code will work with any other date format too, as long as the cells contain real dates and not strings.

[image]

The following code has to be in a module. You need to specify your sheet names.

```
Option Explicit

Global wsData As Worksheet
Global wsDest As Worksheet
Global LastRow As Long
Global LastCol As Long
Global GroupCounter As Long

Public Sub ExtractGroups()
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")                         'specify source sheet
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Groups")                       'specify destination sheet
    LastRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = wsData.Cells(1, wsData.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    GroupCounter = 0

    '## Sort data
    With wsData.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        'sort by Acquistion Date, Document Date and Inactive Date
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E2:E" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F2:F" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G2:G" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .SetRange wsData.UsedRange
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    '## Find first group
    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = LastRow

    Dim IntSum As Double
    Do While IntSum + wsData.Cells(iRow, "C").Value <= 100
        IntSum = IntSum + wsData.Cells(iRow, "C").Value

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        wsDest.Rows(2).Insert xlDown
        wsData.Rows(iRow).Resize(ColumnSize:=LastCol).Copy
        wsDest.Rows(2).Cells(1, "A").Value = GroupCounter
        wsDest.Rows(2).Cells(1, "B").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        iRow = iRow - 1
    Loop

    '## Analyze the data
    Dim GroupRows As Long
    GroupRows = LastRow - iRow

    Dim destRow As Long, FirstGroupRow As Long, FirstDate As Date, AddedRows As Long
    Do While GroupRows >= 0
        GroupCounter = GroupCounter + 1
        FirstGroupRow = 2
        AddedRows = 0
        destRow = 2 + GroupRows - 1
        FirstDate = 0
        GroupRows = 0

        Do While destRow + GroupRows >= FirstGroupRow + GroupRows
            If FirstDate = 0 Then
                If Not IsDate(wsDest.Cells(destRow + GroupRows, "H").Value) Then Exit Do
                FirstDate = wsDest.Cells(destRow + GroupRows, "H").Value
                GroupRows = GroupRows + AddNextOwners(wsDest.Cells(destRow + GroupRows, "H").Value + 1)
            ElseIf FirstDate <> wsDest.Cells(destRow + GroupRows, "H").Value Then
                GroupRows = GroupRows + 1

                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                wsDest.Rows(2).Insert xlDown
                wsDest.Rows(destRow + GroupRows).Resize(ColumnSize:=LastCol - 1).Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Copy
                wsDest.Rows(2).Cells(1, "A").Value = GroupCounter
                wsDest.Rows(2).Cells(1, "B").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            End If

            destRow = destRow - 1
        Loop

        If GroupRows = 0 Then Exit Do

        '## Sort within the group
        With wsDest.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=wsDest.Range("H2").Resize(RowSize:=GroupRows), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange wsDest.Rows("2").Resize(RowSize:=GroupRows)
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

        '## color every second group
        With wsDest.Rows("2").Resize(RowSize:=GroupRows).Interior
            If GroupCounter Mod 2 = 0 Then
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
                .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            Else
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End If
        End With


        '## check if group int exceeds 100 %
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(wsDest.Range("D2").Resize(RowSize:=GroupRows)) > 100 Then
            MsgBox "'Int' in group " & GroupCounter & " exceeded 100 %. Please fix the source data.", vbCritical
            'ReNumberGroups
            Exit Sub
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'ReNumberGroups

    '## everything was going correctly!
    MsgBox "Mission accomplished!", vbInformation
End Sub

'## Substitute the old owner with the new ones (for the next group)
Private Function AddNextOwners(DocDate As Date) As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        If wsData.Cells(iRow, "F").Value = DocDate Then
            AddNextOwners = AddNextOwners + 1

            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            wsDest.Rows(2).Insert xlDown
            wsData.Rows(iRow).Resize(ColumnSize:=LastCol).Copy
            wsDest.Rows(2).Cells(1, "A").Value = GroupCounter
            wsDest.Rows(2).Cells(1, "B").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        End If
    Next iRow
End Function
```

And it will end up with the worksheet `"Groups"` like this below.

Note that the algorithm fails in the end because of some data inconsistency.

[image]

If you want the group numbers the other way round use …

```
Private Sub ReNumberGroups()
    Dim iRow As Long

    Const StartGroupNumber As Long = 1 'define first group number

    For iRow = 2 To wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        wsDest.Cells(iRow, "A").Value = GroupCounter - wsDest.Cells(iRow, "A").Value + StartGroupNumber
    Next iRow
End Sub
```